# Excel VBA: referencing another worksheet using a cell value

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

So I want to get the value of cell in a different worksheet (let's say Wrksheet2) without typing "Wrksheet2". It is already a string value on my main worksheet (Wrksheet1). I want to do this with several different sheets since I have a whole row of the sheet names.

Below is what I want to do

```
Dim SheetNameString as String
Dim SheetWork as Worksheet
Dim i as Integer

for i = 3 to 15
SheetNameString = cells(3,i)
SheetWork = Sheets(SheetNameString)
   If SheetWork.cells(i+4, 8) = blah Then
   Blah blah
   End If

Next
```

So the current sheet, Wrksheet1, row 3 is a row of the sheet names in my workbook. I want to iterate through this row, going cell by cell (name of worksheet by name of worksheet) and go and access that worksheet to perform an If statement using that a value from that sheet (such as Sheets("Wrksheet2").cells(1,1) ).

What I am trying to avoid doing is typing each worksheet name out since I have ~45.

I'm not sure how to feed the cell value, a string, into Sheets(""). Neither of  below works:

```
Dim SheetNameString as String
Dim SheetWork as Worksheet

SheetNameString = cells(3,3)
SheetWork = Sheets(SheetNameString)
```

OR

```
Dim SheetNameString as String
Dim SheetWork as Worksheet

SheetNameString = cells(3,3)
SheetWork = Sheets("SheetNameString")
```

Comment: `Set SheetWork = Sheets(SheetNameString)`

Comment: @taller Unfortunately that does not work when I try that

Comment: What does it do *instead* of work though?

Comment: Please share all your code and error information in your post.

Comment: Dim SheetNameString As String
Dim SheetWork As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

For i = 3 To 15
    SheetNameString = Cells(3, i).Value
    
    ' Use Evaluate to dynamically reference the worksheet
    Set SheetWork = Worksheets(SheetNameString)
    
    ' Check the condition in the specified cell of the referenced worksheet
    If SheetWork.Cells(i + 4, 8).Value = "blah" Then
        ' Your code here
        ' Blah blah
    End If
Next i

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `does not work`.

Answer (score 2):

### Loop Through a Row of Worksheet Names

[image]

```vb
Sub LoopThroughRow()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Master")
    
    Dim srg As Range, scCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range("C3")
        scCount = sws.Cells(.Row, sws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column _
            - .Column + 1
        If scCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No worksheet names found!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set srg = .Resize(, scCount)
    End With
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet, scell As Range, dwsName As String
    
    For Each scell In srg.Cells
        dwsName = CStr(scell.Value)
        On Error Resume Next
            Set dws = wb.Sheets(dwsName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If dws Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Worksheet """ & dwsName & """ not found!", vbExclamation
        Else
            ' Do your 'Blah' code here e.g.:
            MsgBox "Processing worksheet """ & dwsName & """.", vbInformation
            
            Set dws = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration (worksheet)
        End If
    Next scell
    
End Sub
```